# Loading external table returns "An internal error occurred..."

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create external table from google cloud storage backups but both Web UI and bq mk regurn "An internal error occurred..." Does somebody also experience this and any ideas how to ? Creating native table from cloud storage works fine.

Comment: Please file a bug at http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/ and include details that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: looks like this question is not qualified for down-voting. i am up-voting it now. those who down-voted - can you explain reasons? or just change you mind! for me - Jeremy's comment makes this question a good question unless I am missing something

Comment: Filed https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=481